# Ratio summary fields at detail level - Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, report, summary

I'm trying to find a way to show a ratio of a field of interest Vs the sum of the field of intrest and display this at the line details level.

Name:
Profit:
ProfitRatio:

---

ABC
$1000
10%

XYZ
$5000
50%

NMO
$2000
20%

QST
$2000
20%

---

TOTAL $10000

ie ProfitRatio for ABC = Profit / SumProfit = $1000 / $10000 = 10%

Because the totals are calculated after the detail levels I can't understand how to "reuse" the summary in a calculation at the line detail level. I'm guessing its something to do with printing order but I just can't get my head around it.

Any help would be appreciated
Thank B

PS 
crystal version 8.5 & old foxPro .dbf

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, I have since found a report where I did something similar. </br> sum({STOCK.QTY},{STOCK.SUPCODE})/sum({STOCK.QTY})*100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be possible through the following formula.

```
numbervar a;
a:=({Profit}/Sum ({Profit}))*100;
a;
```

Place this formula in *Details* and you will get the ProfitRatio.

Note: Make sure that the fields *Profit* and *SumProfit* are in Numeric Data Type, if they are in string then you have to convert to numeric.

Try this and get back with results. Ready to help you further !

Answer (score 1):

Taking Hariharan Anbazhagan's answer a step farther.  You can use a group sum like this.

```
Sum({field},{group field})
```